# Avoid printing in a for loop on windows batch file

Tags: windows, node.js, batch-file, browserify

It has been ages since the last time I used windows, so I need some help with a simple script that I am trying to create. In a nutshell, I want to generate a script which creates some files based on a list of files. What irritates me is that during the execution of the for loop, after the second element is processed, I start seeing on the output the code for loop itself before the code actually executes. Moreover, my last command of changing directory is never executed and I think the reason is the goto:eof statement that I have. Could someone help me edit the script appropriately?

Here is the script:

```
@echo off
set "myroot=%cd%"
set "scriptsroot=%myroot%\public\javascripts"
set "cdstr=Changing directory"
echo.%cdstr%
cd %scriptsroot%
set "mainmsg=Generating bundles"
echo.%mainmsg%
set "corefiles="definitions resources representation something""
call:myConverter %corefiles%
set "cdstr=Changing directory"
echo.%cdstr%
cd %myroot%

:myConverter
set list=%~1
(for %%f in (%list%) do (
    echo.- Bundle for %%f
    browserify %%f.js -o %%fBundle.js
))
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely source of your problem is that `browserify` is another batch script. Because you do not CALL the script, the batch context ends as soon as it completes, and the ECHO state resumes to what it was before the main script was executed. Even though the batch context is over, the FOR loop continues to execute to completion, with the ECHO state now ON. Because the batch context is over, the rest of your script is not executed after the FOR loop finishes.

You need to use `call browserify`, and you also need an `exit /b` or `goto :eof` before your `:myConverter` label.

But your script seems overly complicated, setting variables that don't seem to have any purpose, saving your current location in a variable instead of using PUSHD/POPD, and an unnecessary subroutine.

I would code your script as follows:

```
@echo off
echo Changing directory
pushd public\javascripts
echo Generating bundles
for %%F in (definitions resources representation something) do (
  echo - Bundle for %%F
  call browserify %%F.js -o %%FBundle.js
)
echo Returning to original directory
popd
```

If you are going to do the conversion in multiple places in a larger script, then fine, create and use a subroutine. But there is no need to create a `list` variable. Simply use `%~1` directly in your FOR loop.

```
:myConverter
for %%F in (%~1) do (
  echo - Bundle for %%F
  call browserify %%F.js -o %%FBundle.js
)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

this will not solve your problem, but I found an logical error in your script:

put an `exit /b` before the label `:myConverter`

When you think, your script is finished with "last" line `cd %myroot%`, it actually goes on with your "subroutine", but `%~1` is empty now, so it tries to execute

```
(for %%f in () do (
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Stephan. Voted up this one as well. You had a point with the exit /b.